# How to correctly read the burst and rate for Rspamd Ratelimit?

Tags: rspamd

What is the following rate limit bucket means in /etc/rspamd/local.d/ratelimit.conf?

```
bucket = [{
         burst = 10; 
         rate = "30 / 1min";
         }]
```

Does it mean like the following?

**The bucket capacity is 10 email. And when there are 30 emails sent from an authenticated sender in 1 minute, then the rest 20 emails sent previously and the new emails would be soft rejected.**

Additional questions:

- But, how much is the duration of the soft reject?
- What is the soft
  reject units in seconds or minutes or hours and where can I find
  them??

Kindly help, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since no one answered, I want to answer my own question.

My final setup:

```
burst = 50;
rate = "30 / 1min";
```

This means:

Each authenticated user can send 30 emails per minute, but not more than 50. When it reached 50, then Rspamd will start to soft reject them, and I saw a window pops out on my outlook telling me that I reached the ratelimit until the next minute.

Hope this also helps someone.